# Search array for string - returning -1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been reading lots of StackOverflow answers which tell me that, in Javascript, the best way to search an array for a particular string is use `indexOf()`. I have been trying to make this work for a while now, and I need some help with it.

I am making a shop in a text-adventure game. These are the values I am using:

The **array** `shopCosts`:

```
shopCosts = [20, 25];
```

The **array** `shopItems`:

```
shopItems = [["Sword", "Shield"]];
```

I **dynamically create radiobuttons** by **looping** through `shopItems`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    // Create the list item:
    var item = document.createElement('li');

    // Set its contents:
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i] + " - " + shopCosts[i] + " Gold"));

    // Add it to the list:
    list.appendChild(item);

    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    var text = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = "shop";
    radio.value = array[i];
    radio.onclick = function () { addValue(this.getAttribute("value"), shopCosts, shopItems) }

    label.appendChild(radio);
    label.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(label); 
}
```

This is the part in question:

```
radio.onclick = function () { addValue(this.getAttribute("value"), shopCosts, shopItems) }
```

My logic was basically to assign values to each dynamically created radiobutton, and if one was pressed, get the value (so, the name of the item you wanted to buy) and then search `shopItems` for that particular string for the index value. Once I had that, I would look in the same "*parallel*" list `shopCosts` to find the price.

I used `console.log()` to see what variables were in play. When I clicked on the radio button, this function is called:

```
function addValue(nameOfItem, shopCosts, shopItems)
{
    var positionOfShopItem = shopItems.indexOf(nameOfItem);
    console.log(positionOfShopItem);
    console..log(nameOfItem);
    console.log(shopItems);
}
```

Surely, the `console.log()` would return the position of the named item? To prove to myself I'm not going crazy, here's what the Dev Tools say:

```
-1
Sword
    [Array[2]]
        0: "Sword"
        1: "Shield"
```

`Sword` is clearly in the array, in position 0, so why is `indexOf()` returning `-1`?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is `shopItems` supposed to be an array of arrays? This - `[["Sword", "Shield"]];` is an array with 1 element, where that one element is an array of 2 elements.

Comment: your `shopItems` is an array of arrays. change `[["Sword", "Shield"]];` to `["Sword", "Shield"];`

Comment: @Jamiec
I only did this because if I don't, the list looks like [this](http://snag.gy/I6HM2.jpg)

Comment: You're looping over the strings in the array then, a string also has a `length` property and you can read an individual character. Basically, strings are an array of characters (for most intents and purposes). In any case, this is unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize you've already fixed the bug, but I urge you to consider a different approach to the problem. These two principles will not only solve the problem in a cleaner way, but they also give you a new way to think about similar problems in the future:

1. Never use parallel arrays. Use a single array of objects instead.
2. In your main loop that appends the items, put the main body of the loop in a function.

If you follow these two ideas you gain several benefits. The code becomes much more straightforward, easier to maintain, and you don't have to do any array lookups at all!

Each shop item is packaged up as a single object in the array, like this:

```
var shopItems = [
    { name: 'Sword', cost: 20 },
    { name: 'Shield', cost: 25 }
];
```

So if you have a reference to the shop item as a whole, say in a variable called `shopItem`, then you automatically have all of its properties available: `shopItem.name` and `shopItem.cost`. This lets you also easily add more bits of data to a shop item, e.g.

```
var shopItems = [
    { name: 'Sword', cost: 20, dangerous: true },
    { name: 'Shield', cost: 25, dangerous: false }
];
```

and now `shopItem.dangerous` will give you the appropriate value. All without any array lookups.

Making the main loop body into a function adds a further benefit: Inside that function, its parameters and local variables are preserved each time you call the function (this is called a closure). So now you don't even have to fetch the list item value and look it up - you already have the appropriate `shopItem` available in the code.

Putting this together, the code might look like this:

```
var shopItems = [
    { name: 'Sword', cost: 20, dangerous: true },
    { name: 'Shield', cost: 25, dangerous: false }
];

var list = document.getElementById( 'list' );

for( var i = 0;  i < shopItems.length;  ++i ) {
    appendShopItem( shopItems[i] );
}

// Alternatively, you could use .forEach() instead of the for loop.
// This will work in all browsers except very old versions of IE:
// shopItems.forEach( appendShopItem );

function appendShopItem( shopItem ) {
    // Create the list item:
    var item = document.createElement( 'li' );

    // Set its contents:
    item.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 
        shopItem.name + ' - ' + shopItem.cost + ' Gold'
    ) );

    // Add it to the list:
    list.appendChild( item );

    var label = document.createElement( 'label' );
    var radio = document.createElement( 'input' );
    var text = document.createTextNode( shopItem.name );
    radio.type = 'radio';
    radio.name = 'shop';
    radio.value = shopItem.name;
    radio.onclick = function () {
        addValue( shopItem );
    };

    label.appendChild( radio );
    label.appendChild( text );
    document.body.appendChild( label ); 
}

function addValue( shopItem ) {
    console.log( shopItem );
    alert(
        shopItem.name +
        ' costs ' + shopItem.cost + ' and is ' +
        ( shopItem.dangerous ? 'dangerous' : 'not dangerous' )
    );
}
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/eat5cunv/4/) (with a tip of the hat to Jamiec for the original fiddle)

As you can see, this makes the code much easier to understand. If you have a `shopItem`, you automatically have its `name`, `cost`, and any other property you want to add. And most importantly, you never have to keep track of putting your values in the same order in two, three, or even more different arrays.

Comment: This is brilliant! I'm going to re-write the Shop Code. I write most of my code in Python, and didn't know there was a structure similar to a Dictionary in Javascript. Thanks for this!

Comment: My pleasure! It's very gratifying to know that I inspired you to pick up some new JavaScript techniques.

Comment: Fun fact: Not only is a JavaScript object much like a Python dictionary, but most other JavaScript types are also objects. For example, arrays are objects and can have named properties in addition to numeric indices, and functions are also objects that can have properties on the function itself, like a class method in Python : `function Test() {};  Test.prop = 'classy';  Test.myClassMethod = function() { alert(this.prop); };  Test.myClassMethod();  // alerts 'classy'` And you can still use `Test.prototype` for when you do `new Test()` to instantiate a `Test` object.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for giving me some extra info.

Comment: Fun(ish) fact: This is the answer I *wanted* to give, thats what I get for answering a question flippantly as I need to run out the door from work. Well played!

Answer (score 5):

As I alluded to in my comment, its because `shopItems` does not contain an array of strings, it contains a single element, where that one element is an array of strings. I suspect your code would work just fine if you removed the extra square braces

```
var shopItems = ["Sword", "Shield"];
```

Answer (score 0):

shopItems is an Array of Arrays. The 0 index of shopItems contains another array which contains:

```
["Sword", "Shield"]
```

So when you are trying to find the "Sword" item or "Shield" Item inside of shopItems it is returning -1 because it cannot find either inside of the array.

Change

```
shopItems = [["Sword", "Shield"]];
```

To

```
shopItems = ["Sword", "Shield"];
```

And that will fix your issue.

Comment: I've tried this. If I remove the double square brackets, the list in the shop consists of single letters, like [this](http://snag.gy/I6HM2.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it!

Removing the double square brackets resulted in [this mess](http://snag.gy/I6HM2.jpg). So, as a workaround, I simply added `[0]` to `var positionOfShopItem = shopItems.indexOf(nameOfItem);` to get `var positionOfShopItem = shopItems[0].indexOf(nameOfItem);`

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: I think you may be getting your .length functions mixed up. I think you are getting the length of the characters of the string in the first array position. I also don't know what array is. You are using it in the code above. You are using array.length and array[i], but you should be using shopItems.length and shopItems[i] correct?